# Function of a curve if area and boundary conditions provided

Tags: calculus, area

I'm trying to solve for the function of a curve if the following parameters are provided:

1. The (integral) area  under the curve is given from an initial $t_0 = 0$ to $t_1 = b$ (NOTE: $b$ is not given)
2. The boundary conditions at the initial and final location are given $y(t_0)=0, y(t_1)=5$.

Can anyone provide any advice on what methods I should use to solve for the function?

Comment: On point 1, do you mean just one value representing the area under the curve between those two endpoints, or are you saying that for each $t$ in that range, you know the area under the curve between $0$ and $t$? If the former, then your problem in underspecified and there are infinitely many solutions (indeed, an infinite dimensional space of solutions). If the latter, then there is only one function that satisfies 1 - the derivative of the area function. Whether that function will also meet 2 depends on the function. Either way, the problem doesn't seem sensible. Is there any more info?

Comment: Specifically for these two points. I tried to find the time difference from $t_0$ to $t_1$ using the following => $A$/$f(t_1)$ = $\delta t$ where A is the area and $f(t_1)$ is the value of the function at $t_1$

Comment: Then as I noted, there is a vast infinity of functions that satisfy your conditions. It is impossible to determine the function or the width of the interval from the given information. For example, if the area is $5$, then one solution would be $b = 2, f(t) = \frac 5 2 t$. But another solution would be $b = \frac 3 2$ and $$f(t) = \begin{cases} 5t & t \le 1\\5 & 1 < t\end{cases}$$ A third is $b = 3, f(t) = \frac 5 9 t^2$.